# Distinguishing between didSelectRowAtIndexPath and accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I've implemented didSelectRowAtIndexPath and accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath never seems to fire. However, didSelectRowAtIndexPath always fires, even when I click the accessory. Shouldn't these two be exclusive?

Comment: What `accessoryType` are you using? `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` is the only type that will fire the latter method.

Comment: You are correct.  Can you post as an answer so I can accept?  Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [DisclosureIndicator does not detect touches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8389314/disclosureindicator-does-not-detect-touches)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`-[UITableViewDelegate accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:]` is only called when the `accessoryType` of the cell is set to `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`.