# DisclosureIndicator does not detect touches

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uikit

I am using `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator` as `accessoryType` of my `UITableViewCell`. According to Apple's documentation, the data source method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

should automatically get called.

> If the cell is enabled and the accessory type is UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton, the accessory view tracks touches and, when tapped, sends the data-source object a tableView:accessoryButtonTappedForRowWithIndexPath: message.

here's my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
[cell.textLabel setText:[datasource objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
}
```

The data source method is just a `NSLog` but nothing is printed...

Am I missing something? (of course, data source and delegate are set properly)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The answer is in your question. You said

> I am using UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator as
>   accessoryType ...

and you quoted the Apple docs in part

> If the cell is enabled and the accessory type is UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton ...

Only when you use `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton` is the delegate method called. The difference, of course, is that this is a button, where `UITableViewCellAccesssoryDisclosureIndicator` is not. When you use the latter, tapping it is like tapping the cell itself. You could create a custom cell and implement `hitTest:` to determine if the tap was "near" the disclosure indicator, but that seems like more work than necessary (unless you *really* don't want to use a detail disclosure button).

Answer (score 0):

Check out the names of the accessory indicators `UITableViewCellAccessoryNone,`                                          `UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator,`           `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton`    `UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark,`                                        `UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailButton`

Only detail button and detail disclosure button receives taps and calls the method . U may use UIGestureRecognizer and a custom method .